# Difficulties in making right Angular`s guard

Tags: angular, guard

My task is simple is it can be, but I don understand why it doesnt work well.
I try to make a guard which protect route from all except users which have "admin" role.

How do I check? I send request to my api server with user api_token, server checks the token, and send me response with "true" (has role) or false.
In this part all working perfect.
Problem appears when I try to use this response exactly in guard

There are the code of my service, and my guard.
First one:

```
    isAdmin(apiToken: string): Observable<string> {
    const params = new FormData();
    params.append('api_token', apiToken);
    return this.http.post(this.urlConfig.IS_ADMIN, params)
      .pipe(map(resp => ResultResponse.fromJson(resp)))
      .pipe(map(ResResp => ResResp.response));
  }
```

Guard:

```
admin = false;
token;

constructor(private httpAuthService: HttpAuthService,
              @Inject(MessagesService) private msgService: MessagesService, private pRouter: Router) {
  }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokenData'));
      this.token = data.api_token;
    }
    if (this.token) {
      this.isAdmin();
      if (this.admin) {
        return true;
      }
      this.redirectAndLogin();
    }
    this.redirectAndLogin();
  }

  private redirectAndLogin() {
    this.msgService.loginWindowShow();
    this.Router.navigate(['/main']);
    return false;
  }

  private isAdmin() { 
    this.httpAuthService.isAdmin(this.token).subscribe(r => {
      this.admin = r === 'true';
    });
  }
```

In case of service, it send to guard "true" or "false", yes in string type, but it works well.
But admin properties still false, isAdmin method doesnt change this property to "true". And guard all the time redirect me to the login form.
Why does it happen?

Comment: apply checks in browser and debug once.

Comment: The problem is that you work with asynchronous code meanwhile trying to do a check synchronously using a callback what doesn't work. You can return `Observable` or `Promise` in guard so that your asynchronous checks will happen for sure and only after that you will process on your flow.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you trying to asign the `this.admin` value in the `isAdmin()` function but you don't know when it get precasily assigned to the `admin` property because its asynchronous code.

The solution is simple just insted of using subsribing to do a map which transforms the value to boolean, then use tab for redirecting.

Like so:

```
private isAdmin() { 
  return this.httpAuthService.isAdmin(this.token).pipe(map(r => r === 'true'));
}
```

Can activate function:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
  Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  if (localStorage.length > 0) {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokenData'));
    this.token = data.api_token;
  }
  this.isAdmin()
    .pipe(tab(r => {
       if(!r) {
         this.redirectAndLogin();
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. Your solution doesnt work properly (I dont know why, 'tap' give me nothing) but give me some tips, and I solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, you`re absolutely right. Let me return to your solution, it doesnt work, what i do wrong?

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokenData'));
      this.token = data.api_token;
    }
    if (this.token) {
      this.isAdmin()
        .pipe(tap(r => {
          console.log(r); 
// In this line console.log shows me nothing, as i see, "pipe" doesnt work properly, why it happens?
          if (!r) {
            this.redirectAndLogin();
          }
        }));
      return true;
    }
    this.redirectAndLogin();
  }

private isAdmin(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.httpAuthService.isAdmin(this.token).pipe(map(r => r === 'true'));
  }
```

And I reply my method in service again, maybe trouble starts something here:

```
isAdmin(apiToken: string): Observable<string> {
    const params = new FormData();
    params.append('api_token', apiToken);
    return this.http.post(this.urlConfig.IS_ADMIN, params)
      .pipe(map(resp => ResultResponse.fromJson(resp)))
      .pipe(map(ResResp => ResResp.response));
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for all answers. I simplified my guard, and it works. Below is the answer:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokenData'));
      this.token = data.api_token;
    }
    if (this.token) {
      this.httpAuthService.isAdmin(this.token).subscribe(r => {
        if (!r) { this.redirectAndLogin(); }
      });
      return true;
    }
    this.redirectAndLogin();
  }

  private redirectAndLogin() {
    this.msgService.loginWindowShow();
    this.Router.navigate(['/main']);
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Hi i like to see you resolved it, but you use not nice practice and i will give you a example why is this a bad practise. You let user go to the roote before you know if is admin or not. Once you subsribe to something you are using async code which means you don't know when the code in subsribe will be executed. thats exactly why i used tab operator. The example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amfvkf

Comment: Ok, thanks I see where is my fault. But I dont understand, how can I get an HttpClient answer without .subscribe? "An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method" - angular.io said the same =)

Comment: When you return Observable<boolean> from the CanActivate it will automaticaly subscribe for you. just map what ever the HTTP client returns to boolean.